# optimize sql queries for comparing an array

Tags: sql, arrays, performance, algorithm, compare

I have about 100-800 words (user input) I want to match to 50 keywords (in a SQL database). Since this is going to be on a web app I want to make it optimized. I'm a beginner with SQL and wanting to know what the efficient ways of doing this are.

Right now I have the words with their hash stored in the database.

- take the input
- go through each word  and calc it's hash
- put the hash code into an array in order (don't need duplicates)
- then I search each one (all I need to know if there is a key word that is there)

ie iterate for all members in the hashcode array:

```
SELECT * 
FROM hash_table
WHERE hash_code = hash_var;
```

Comment: Please post your query trial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running the a query against the database for each or is very ineffective.. you are going to run 100-800 querys (ouch).. one solution maybe running all of the in one query (using the `IN()` operator) but that still means sending the all of the text to the database.. since the database only as 50 words.. (even if more).. I think you will perform better if you SELECT all of the words into an list, and do the comparison on C#.. where then you can optimize and fetch the list only once.. before you do the 100-800 comparisons

Comment: ansered my question in a way. I'm working on making my questions better. It's a very good suggestion and that's a big thing I was looking for. Thank you for your response